# JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, war

I'm currently cleaning up my Project and related Errors / Warnings a bit. Everytime i deploy my Maven Project to the JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final I get a lot of Warnings.

I found a lot of posts / comments stating to just ignore or hide those warnings.

Okay, warnings are just warnings, but however it should be possible to resolve the *reason* for the warnings, instead of just hiding or ignoring those warnings (Because I think: What is a warning NOW, can become an error at some other point)

```
09:51:55,145 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "oce2.war"
09:51:56,241 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ConfigurableArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.spi.Configurable'
09:51:56,242 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.GenericArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'
09:51:56,244 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'
09:51:56,245 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=UNKNOWN' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'
09:51:56,246 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.serialization.ZipSerializableViewImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.serialization.SerializableView'
09:51:56,248 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.JavaArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'
09:51:56,249 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'
09:51:56,250 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'
09:51:56,251 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.tar.TarExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarExporter'
09:51:56,253 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarExporter'
09:51:56,254 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ZipImporter'
09:51:56,255 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ZipImporter'
09:51:56,256 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.tar.TarImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarImporter'
09:51:56,258 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarImporter'
09:51:56,259 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.WebArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'
09:51:56,260 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.war' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'
09:51:56,261 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'
09:51:56,262 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.tar.TarGzExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarGzExporter'
09:51:56,264 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar.gz' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarGzExporter'
09:51:56,265 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.serialization.ZipSerializableViewImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.serialization.ZipSerializableView'
09:51:56,266 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.ExplodedImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ExplodedImporter'
09:51:56,268 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.ExplodedExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ExplodedExporter'
09:51:56,270 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.EnterpriseArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'
09:51:56,271 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.ear' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'
09:51:56,272 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'
09:51:56,274 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.ResourceAdapterArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'
09:51:56,276 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.rar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'
09:51:56,278 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'
09:51:56,279 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.tar.TarGzImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarGzImporter'
09:51:56,280 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar.gz' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarGzImporter'
09:51:56,281 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.zip.ZipExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ZipExporter'
```

edit:

I already found the solution - just always forgot to save the pom-file and thought it wasn't working.

I added the shrinkwrap dependency to the pom file:

```
<dependency>       
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-impl-base</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What's the actual solution?  Not everyone uses Maven.

Comment: @rob If you dont use maven, you Need to add the dependencys manually. you can find the shrinkwrap jars here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/shrinkwrap.htm

Comment: I don't know what this is flagged as too localized. I have the same issue and would like to know an answer. However, adding those dependencies does not seem to fix it for me. I am using Maven.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. Does "too localized" mean that problems with maven are too localized? Or that error messages that don't seem to have a visible bug associated are too localized?

Answer (score 2):

In my case most of the warnings "JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name..." went away after I have set the correct scope for all dependencies regarding arquillian and shrinkwrap to "test", e.g.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
 <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi</artifactId>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the edit by OP,

add these dependencies to the pom:

```
<dependency>       
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-impl-base</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```