# JBoss startup warning : MSC service thread ... Invalid class name

Tags: jboss, jboss-weld

I want to get rid of the WARN messages in the following JBoss console output.

```
08:46:53,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "IodLogin.war"
08:46:53,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
08:46:53,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
08:46:54,124 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
08:46:54,124 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
08:46:54,596 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment IodLogin.war
08:46:54,815 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: IodLogin.war
08:46:54,858 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-10) WELD-000900 1.1.10 (redhat)
08:46:54,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.IodLogin.war:main" from Service Module Loader
08:46:54,904 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment IodLogin.war
08:46:55,269 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-13) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
08:46:55,327 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-13) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.13-jbossorg-1 20121010-0442 for context '/IodLogin'
08:46:55,933 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-13) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final-redhat-2
08:46:56,281 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-13) Monitoring jndi:/default-host/IodLogin/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
```

This is "just" a warning message, and I doubt it has any direct negative effect, but I try to avoid warning messages that might distract me and others from a warning that shouldn't be ignored -- the "Boy who cried 'Wolf'" parable.

I'm not using Tomcat or Jetty, but it looks like some configuration file or code is referring to classes specific to those environments.  I've verified that none of the XML files refer to them directly.

I'm running JBoss EAP 6.0.1.GA.  So far, this JSF 2.0 application is pretty simple -- just one page and a few classes.  I'm using Eclipse, without Maven.  [Elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777560), I found a reference to `org.jboss.shrinkwrap`, but I don't see how that applies to my situation.

**Update:**  My question is along the line of "how do I make this symptom of a non-problem go away so it doesn't mask a real problem".  I'm not looking for a mistake in my code, just an improvement in the configuration.

Any suggestions about where I should look?

Comment: Ahh.. that is a warning that I see in my JBoss stack trace as well. I guess it comes with the JBoss. So, nothing that you did wrong or something.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12777560/132374