# JBoss AS 7.2 Failed to determine implementation class name

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

When I am trying to call a WSDL-based web service from inside a Resource Adapter, I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE [org.apache.cxf.BusFactory] (JmsMessageDispatcher#2) Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name.: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3126) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getBusFactoryClass(BusFactory.java:333) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:260) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:247) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:99) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.createThreadBus(BusFactory.java:193) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:182) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:166) [cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.configureObject(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:99) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:131) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:155) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
```

During deployment of said Resource Adapter, I get this warning:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext,org.springframework.beans.BeansException' for service type 'org.apache.cxf.bus.factory'
```

I guess it is like they say: A warning DOES become an error sooner or later ;)

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777560/jbas015893-encountered-invalid-class-name) question didn't help, since I added the following dependency to my pom.xml already like so:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.9</version>    
</dependency>
```

The Resource Adapter is deployed as a JCA Connector (.rar).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How does your deployment structure look like? what are the jars in your lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't deliver Spring and CXF with your resource adapters. Include them as module dependency.

In your RA project:

- pom.xml: use provided scope for CXF libraries
- add META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to RAR archive

META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client" services="import" />
      <module name="org.apache.cxf"> <!-- .impl removed -->
        <imports>
          <include path="META-INF" />
          <include path="META-INF/cxf" />
        </imports>
      </module>
      <module name="org.springframework.spring">
        <imports>
          <include path="META-INF" />
        </imports>
      </module>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

As spring is not part of JBoss you have to deploy it as new module.

- Create module directory $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/springframework/spring/main/
- add module.xml
- add the JAR files listed in module.xml to the directory

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.springframework.spring">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar" />
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar" />
    <resource-root path="spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar" />
    <resource-root path="spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar" />
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar" />
    <resource-root path="spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar" />
</resources>
<dependencies>       
    <module name="javax.api" />
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
    <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
</dependencies>
</module>
```

I'm not sure if this is a class-loading bug deep down in JBoss or not.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I wonder why I need Spring, though. I don't recall using it anywhere.

Comment: cxf is based on spring though programmatic configuration is possible.